# javascript load more button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to copy the post from https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-a-load-more-button-to-your-content.stml to add the load more button.

However, it's not working. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arya107/b2k5h1oh/), and here I have inserted the JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".moreBox").slice(0, 3).show();
  if ($(".blogBox:hidden").length != 0) {
    $("#loadMore").show();
  }
  $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".moreBox:hidden").slice(0, 6).slideDown();
    if ($(".moreBox:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

I am looking to have 3 posts show at a time on my website blog section.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here but this is definitely wrong: `<id="loadMore">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML markup is not OK

This line is wrong: `<id="loadMore"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</a>`

Maybe you want:

```
 <div id="loadMore"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</a></div>
```

I just updated the js in the fiddle, it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".moreBox").slice(0, 3).show();
  if ($(".blogBox:hidden").length != 0) {
    $("#loadMore").show();
  }
  $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".moreBox:hidden").slice(0, 6).show().slideDown(); // Updated this line
    if ($(".moreBox:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: or just move the id to the anchor

Comment: Thank You Damian!!

Comment: @Damian Can you please explain me what are you doing in this line $(".moreBox:hidden").slice(0, 6).show().slideDown();

Comment: If you look into the fiddle, the elements are hidden using `display: none`, with `show()` you set display as 'block', and then you apply the slideDown effect

Comment: From jQuery docs: "The .slideDown() method animates the height of the matched elements". show() set the display property, and slideDown() just set the height.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarvan_Kumar_4040/b2k5h1oh/30/)

I have added jquery.min.js file.

Updated this line as well.

```
<div class="text-center pb-5" id="loadMore">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have basic things wrong here that you should be able to observe at a glance.

1) Syntax error as highlighted in the code editor:

```
<id="loadMore"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Load More</a>
```

Does that look like valid HTML to you? Move the ID attribute to the anchor tag.

2) jQuery Slim doesn't have a slideDown function - it's the slim version

You could have observed that by opening the console after fixing your syntax issue and noticing that there was an exception about the non-existing function.

3) While the code will now work, it will only work for a maximum of 6 items, think you can guess why!

```
$(".moreBox:hidden").slice(0, $(".moreBox:visible").length + 3).slideDown();
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ecxervpj/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I'm relatively new to web design, so go easy on me haha. How can I make it hold more? Do I need to change the value of 6 to however many posts?

Comment: Hah np, you could keep track with a variable or change it as above in my edited answer to keep it simple

Answer (score 0):

change your jQuery.. I hope this code helpful to you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#loadMore").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".moreBox").show();
      });
});
```